# Inter-process communication for python

Tags: python, process

I'm having a problem creating a inter-process communication for my python application. I have two python scripts at hand, let's say A and B. A is used to open a huge file, keep it in memory and do some processing that Mysql can't do, and B is a process used to query A very often.

Since the file A needs to read is really large, I hope to read it once and have it hang there waiting for my Bs' to query.

What I do now is, I use cherrypy to build a http-server. However, I feel it's kind of awkward to do so since what I'm trying to do is absolutely local. So, I'm wondering are there other more organic way to achieve this goal?

I don't know much about TCP/socket etc. If possible, toy examples would be appreciate (please include the part to read file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has good support for ZeroMQ, which is much easier and more robust than using raw sockets.

The ZeroMQ site treats Python as one of its primary languages and offers copious Python examples in its documentation. Indeed, the example in "Learn the Basics" is written in Python.

Comment: Thx! I tried it out, and works like charm. Actually it's so simple that I just checked the page: http://nichol.as/zeromq-an-introduction